# using SMO .net to backup and restore through DeviceType.Pipe

Tags: sql-server, backup, pipe, named-pipes, smo

I wrote a Program that backup SQL Databases using SMO Library on .net , and everything is just going smoothly, I just have one last point, I'm changing my way to save the .bak file on the hard disk, from DeviceType.File to DeviceType.Pipe, I have used pipes before, I just didn't know how to implement it here .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought PIPE backup device was not available in SQL Server 2005 and above.

From [`sys.backup_devices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178018(SQL.90).aspx), pipe is obsolete.
I could be wrong of course, and I've never used pipe backups (even back to my SQL Server 6.5 days)

Edit, OK found it...

1st entry here: [Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262(SQL.90).aspx)

> Discontinued feature = **Named pipe backup devices**
>
> With comment
> "For security reasons, SQL Server does not support backup to named pipes."

So why is it still listed in the [DeviceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.devicetype(SQL.90).aspx) enumeration?

Comment: I think the enum is still available to be able to read in SMO when the backup device is actually configured as pipe. Many features that are obsolete and forbidden in language can still show up in metadata, usually as a result of an instance or database upgrade, and SMO must be able to represent what is actually in the metadata in its object model.

Comment: so is there any alternative way so I can handle the output from the SQL server as a stream of data , cuz My point is I would like to manipulate that stream of data BEFORE saving it on the HD , to save time and for security purposes .

Answer (score 1):

Pipe is discontinued guys. 100% sure